# SOAP/XML-RPC Admin Role in Magento Enterprise?

Tags: soap, extensions

I can´t find the SOAP/XML-RPC Admin/User creation.
Is that already available in EE 1.7.1 or did this come later?

Can I use the SOAP API instead for these things or is this not possible?

I would need it for the Trustpilot Integration.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a user from system configuration, or programmatically?

Comment: I just want to create a user like that but the integration instructions use xml rpc and I can't see that

Comment: Creating admin user / role over SOAP sounds likely to cause some security headaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$userapi = Mage::getModel('api/user')
    ->setData(array(
    'username' => 'server@server.com',
    'firstname' => 'nikhil',
    'lastname' => 'ravindran',
    'email' => 'server@server.com',
    'api_key' => 'myp@ssw0rd',
    'api_key_confirmation' => 'myp@ssw0rd',
    'is_active' => 1,
    'user_roles' => '',
    'assigned_user_role' => '',
    'role_name' => '',
    'roles' => array(1) // your created custom role
    ));
$userapi->save();
$userapi->setRoleIds(array(1))  // your created custom role
    ->setRoleUserId($userapi->getUserId())
    ->saveRelations();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014676

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create Magento Soap User.

First of all you should create Soap Role.
So please go to admin panel `System->Web service->Roles` (after EE-1.12: `System->Web service->SOAP/XML-RPC - Roles`) and Add New Role.

Next step go to `System->Web service->Users` (`System->Web service->SOAP/XML-RPC - Users`) and create new User. **User Name** and **API key** from this step will be used by other applications to connect Magento SOAP API.

Comment: So only after EE-1.12 the SOAP/XML-RPC Roles exist?
Will the SOAP User do the same?